# Ignore new line in Regular Expression Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my textarea, I wanna allow only some specific characters. I also wanna allow new lines. But whatever I try, I'm seeing error if I press enter.

My ViewModel

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Message is required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
[RegEx(RegexValidation.Message, RegexOptions.Singleline, ErrorMessage = "Unsupported character found")]
public string Message { get; set; }
```

The regular expression

```
public const string Message = @"^[+-=()&%""? _,@.A-Za-z0-9].*$";
```

My custom validation attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class RegExAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
    public string Pattern { get; set; }
    public RegexOptions Options { get; set; }
    public RegExAttribute(string pattern) : this(pattern, RegexOptions.None) { }
    public RegExAttribute(string pattern, RegexOptions options)
    {
        Pattern = pattern;
        Options = options;
    }
    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val", "true");
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val-regex", ErrorMessage);
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val-regex-pattern", Pattern);
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(value.ToString(), Pattern, Options);
    }
}
```

This property is a textarea. I'm still seeing error in jQuery unobtrusive when hitting enter for a new line. What is going wrong here?

Comment: have you tried disabling the client-side validation? the server validation should work fine. I doubt that the regex options `RegexOptions.SingleLine` is not transferred to the client-side logic. You can try embedding the options right into the regex pattern instead.

Comment: you may have to manually convert all the regex options into a new pattern. So `Pattern` should be modified in the method `AddValidation`. e.g: the modified pattern can be `$"(?s){Pattern}"` (`(?s)` is to turn on the single-line mode). However I've just found out that javascript does not support such an expression of turning on the single-line mode. So you may have to change the pattern `^[+-=()&%""? _,@.A-Za-z0-9].*$` into `^[+-=()&%""? _,@.A-Za-z0-9](.|\n)*$`

Comment: @Hopeless Thanks man I see the problem now. And your pattern also works. Post it a an answer and I'll accept

Comment: looks like you have your own solution as well, so just go ahead with your answer and you can freely use what I commented here. I just like commenting around for simple things (and also unsure things) like this. So never mind :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can look javascript. your search key: 'dislabled keypress with Enter'

Comment: he may not mean to disable that key, actually looks like he means to allow that key stroke (multiple lines). But the client-side validation currently prevents the text from being submitted (because of it containing at least one line break char `\n` which is not matched by the regex validation pattern).